# how to get $formBuilder->getForm() for a webform

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-webform

I am trying to display my webform in a modal (including error/validation messages inside the modal). I am following this [approach for a custom drupal form](https://makedrupaleasy.com/articles/drupal-8-creating-modal-windows-pop-ups-form-and-send-mail-programmatically) which is not a webform. I am wondering whether this is possible at all with webforms and in case it is, what I need to take into account to make it run?

The first problem I am having is the following code line from the example's `TeacherContactController.php`

```
$modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\tl_session\Form\TeacherForm');
```

When I try to use this in my own controller, I cannot get the webform's proper namespace + id. When I check my webform with devel it says:

```
[__CLASS__] => Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform
  [id] => add_news_webform
```

But I get a "The form argument Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform\webform-submission-add_news_webform-form is not a valid form" error. I tried many things, but did not succeed.

How can I get the webform with formBuilder and what else am I missing here (like webform specific ajax settings etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to hard-code the namespace + ID in a string?

That'd be my first guess as to your problem

try

```
$modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm(Drupal\tl_session\Form\TeacherForm::class);
```

Or possibly

```
$modal_form = $this->formBuilder->getForm(\Drupal\tl_session\Form\TeacherForm::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the webform_devel.module you can use the API tab which provides some example code. (/webform/contact/api)

@see [\Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm::submitWebformSubmission](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/WebformSubmissionForm.php#n2559)